# Find out the row index at which the column value stays constant until its tail end

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, rows

I have pd.df that stores time-history of several sensors. Column 0 is 'Time' (common for all sensors) and columns 1:N are sensor1, sensor2 ... sensorN. Some sensors (when they fail) register a value of 0 and continue to register 0 for the remainder of time history. I would like to create a log of which sensors failed and at which time. So for the given sample df in image 1 I would like something similar to image 2. I currently iterate through columns then rows, going over each cell to identify when the sensor failed. Although this works, its terribly slow for dataframes with a huge amount of sensor data. Is there a better/faster way for doing this in Pandas?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXtz4.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnD2B.png)

Comment: In image 2, sensor4 has a value of 1, but the sensor seems to be working as non-zero values follow. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
sensors_mask = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains("sensor")]
df[sensors_mask].apply(lambda x: x == 0).cumsum().apply(lambda x : get_failure(x)).T
def get_failure(x: pd.Series) -> int:
    if x.max() == 1:
        return x.index[x==1][0] + 1
    else:
        return x.index[x==2] + 1
```

If it is desired behavior that sensor4 has the value of 1 although it doesn't seem to fail, then the code above should imo give what you need. If not, the get_one_or_two function should be modified to return nan if only one occurrence of zero takes place.
To elaborate more on the thinking behind this, by applying the first lambda function, we get the value True for every field that is equal to 0 and False otherwise. With cumsum, True is converted to 1 and False to zero. So for example sensor3 column will become 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Then the get_failure function says that if the maximum value of a column is 1, then give me the index of the first occurrence of 1 plus 1 so as to get the Time value. One could also just return 1 there, but I didn't know whether negative values are a possibility here.
If there is another maximum, then we need the index of the occurrence of 2 plus 1 which signifies the row where repeated zeros start happening. After that, I just transpose the result using .T to bring it to the format that you wanted

Comment: could you elaborate how this works? I'm a beginner at pandas, pardon my ignorance.

Comment: what is df[sensors_mask] and x in get_failure(x) here?

Comment: My apologies. I forgot one line where sensors_mask was defined :).
As for x in get_failure, it corresponds to every column this function is applied to, so in our case every column that contains the word sensor, as defined by the sensors_mask.

Comment: I added a description of the thinking behind this in the answer

Comment: thanks for that explanation, it certainly helps. Follow up: sensors always start w/ a value 0 at time 1, some sensors however start picking up values at a later time instant, for example sensorX could be [0,0,0,0,1,2,0,-1,0,0]. Here I would like to register failure at time = 9. Also sensors values could cross over 0 (as sensorX at time = 7). I can't seem to figure how this approach works here. Would it be helpful to run the first lambda function in reverse order?

Comment: An idea would probably be to execute this line gradually and check the resulting dataframes. I.e. first up to the first apply, then include cumsum(), etc.